# Div position is 0 after loading

Tags: jquery, html

After loading a page the position of a div is 0,0.
But it is located correctly. How to get the right position right in the beginning?
I made an example to [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hA3Uz/) which shows the problem. After clicking the button the position values are correct.

```
<div data-role="page" id="homepage">

    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Home</h1>

    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" id="homecontent">     
<p><a href="#page1">Page1</a></p>        
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page1</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" id="page1content">      

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->

====

jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    initThis();
});    


function initThis() {

    $('#page1content').append('<div id="isodivi"></div>').trigger("create");
    $('#isodivi').height(100);
    $('#isodivi').width(600);
    $('#isodivi').css( "background-color", "lightgreen" );
    var test = $('#isodivi').position().left +" "+ $('#isodivi').position().top;
    $('#isodivi').html(test);
    $('#isodivi').append('<a href="#" data-role="button" id="button1">Click</a>').trigger("create");
}    

$('#button1').click(function() {
var test = $('#isodivi').position().left +" "+ $('#isodivi').position().top;
$('#isodivi').html(test);        
});
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I find the wording of this question confusing. What are you trying to do? What do you expect to happen? What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry. I try to locate other elements to this div using the position values. The other div elements are located incorrectly because of the wrong position values of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/hA3Uz/1/

The problem is that in your unedited code, position of the `div` is put into `test` when the div  doesn't exist, try adding:

```
alert(test);
```

in your  `initThis()` function (right after you give a value to `test`) and you'll hopefully understand what I mean.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I understand now the reason for this.